# Is it possible to have multiple branches open simultaneously in ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

My team oftentimes is working on multiple simultaneous branches from the same trunk. Our folder structure often looks like:

```
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-101\
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-123\
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-555\
...
```

In each branch, then, we have the standard:

```
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-101\.settings
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-101\assets
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-101\bin
...
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-123\.settings
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-123\assets\
D:\Trunk\App\Branch-123\bin
...
```

Currently, to switch between development on different branches, I'm removing the first project from my workspace and then adding the second project. If I try to import a second project without deleting the first, I get an error message saying:

```
"Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"
```

Is there anyway to work around this so that I can open multiple branches simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've used is to have multiple workspaces, one for each branch. The workspaces can even be opened simultaneously, if you want to work on different branches side-by-side.

If each branch named the project differently, then you could open them in the same workspace at the same time. To rename a project, right-click on it and choose *Refactor* > *Rename*.